# asynchronous processing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

on my page load I am loading few list, also on my page I have filter conditions which is taking around 30 seconds to get the filtered records from the database, reason : Database is big and I have to navigate to 9 tables to get the list of records depending upon the selected values.

What is the simplest way to achieve asynchronous processing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you structuring your SQL? If you have to access 9 tables it seems like a view would be a more appropriate solution than joining 9 tables.

Answer (score 0):

- When you page load is finished, d an ajax call with jquery to a service. That services generates the output html that you need. You can place a loader in the div/table where the table is going to be displayed
- Maybe you should refactor your query, 30 seconds is really long. Are you using keys, indexes, temp tables, full text searches, ect ect to optimize your query